# NullPointerException error after trying to call a method from another class Java Selenium TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception, testng

I have 2 classes: ClassA, where I'm trying to call the method from class ClassB:

```
public class ClassA {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void methodA() {
        ClassB.methodB();
        driver.get("https://example.com");
    }
}
```

And ClassB, where the needed method exists:

```
public class ClassB {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void methodB() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Autotests\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work at all. I succeed to open the browser using methodB, but then the URL cannot be opened and in console I see the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at autotests_groups_v1.ClassA.bookingProcess(BookingAnonyomus.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
...
```

I tried different ways to call the method from another class, but basically the error in console is the same every time. So I suppose it's not the root of the issue.
That is why it would good if someone explain me what exactly cause this error in my case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: driver is a property of classB.  Use driver=ClassB.driver maybe?  Or pass classB into classA via constructor...  this is an architecture issue, maybe you just want to have one class here... if using two, maybe your initialization method is in ClassB, and you return the driver to the method call... (if ClassB is just for utility methods...)

Comment: I can't use it all in 1 class. I have different classes now, and I'm trying to avoid the duplication of the code by using methods from another classes.
Anyway, the point you mentioned about using driver from class ClassB is right , and it works now! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `ClassB.methodB();` you initialize `driver` field in `ClassB`. Then when you return from the method and proceed to `driver.get("https://example.com");` you are using `driver` field of `ClassA` so you obviously get NPE since it is still `null`.

Comment: Thank you, Alexey.
Indeed, that was the problem, and I fixed it according to the comment from pcalkins by using the driver from class ClassB: 
driver=ClassB.driver 
Not sure if it's the best option, but it works anyway.